# Minimum Stay in UK on work visa before applying for a Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas

I have tier 2 work visa and I landed in the UK on 20th August. Is there any minimum stay required (e.g. at least 3 months completed in UK) before I apply for Schengen visa?

One of my friends applied for a German visa, and his application got rejected.

Comment: You may have the requirement turned backwards. They require 3 months validity on your UK visa beyond your Schengen exit date.

Comment: Yes I do have stay until 2022 in UK. What do you mean by requirement turned backwards?

Comment: @Rahul if you are staying until the end of December 2022, then you may not get a Schengen visa after the end of September 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no minimum UK stay required for you. You are a 'permanent' resident there (for where to make a Schengen visa application purposes) from the day you arrive. It is not even *essential* to apply from the country of your permanent residency, though one needs a very good reason not to.

Comment: It doesn't look like he's a _permanent_ resident, at least not until he applies for ILR in five years from now.

Comment: I am not a permanent resident. I have a work permit which is valid until 2022.

Comment: I want to apply now as I want to travel to Netherlands in Christmas. That's  why asking whether I need minimum stay or not. If Yes, then I have wait until last November.

Comment: Schengen applications must (generally) be lodged with the consulate serving the applicant's place of residence. It's not necessary for the applicant to be *permanently* resident in the consulate's jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

While applying schengen visa you need to submit last three months pay slip and bank statement. So this indirectly states that you should have stayed 3 months inside UK. Hope this helps.